# Do surjective $u$-Substitutions produce erroneous integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, indefinite-integrals

Let's say I want to integrate the following  $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I make the substitution $u^2 = 1-x^2$

$$\begin{align} 
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx &= -\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2}}du \\ 
&= -\int \frac{u}{|u|}du \\
&= \begin{cases}-\int du \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{   if    }  \  u> 0\\ \\ \int u du \ \ \ \ \  \text{   if    }  \ u< 0\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}-u + C \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \text{   if    }  \  u> 0\\ \\ u + C \ \ \ \ \  \text{   if    }  \ u< 0\end{cases}
\\
&= \begin{cases}-\sqrt{1-x^2} + C \ \ \  \text{   if    }  \  u> 0 \ \ (1)\\ \\ \sqrt{1-x^2} + C\ \ \ \ \  \text{   if    }  \ u< 0 \ \ (2)\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

But only $(1)$ is valid, and $(2)$ is incorrect. Have I introduced an extraneous integral by making the surjective substitution $u^2 = 1- x^2$? Similar to how $x=2 \not\iff x^2 = 4$

As a last side question, do $u$-Substitutions only work if the function being substituted is injective or bijective?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx &= -\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2}}du \\ 
&= -\int \frac{u}{|u|}du \\
&= -\vert u\vert+C\\
&= -\sqrt{1-x^2}+C
\end{align}

As to the surjective question, notice that when we substitute $u^2=1-x^2$ we are already assuming that $u>0$ because of the $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the denominator of the integrand.

Comment: Oh, so the integral is defined only for $x \in (-1, 1)$ and $u > 0\ \  \forall x \in  (-1, 1)$, correct?

Comment: Correct. Note that @lab bhattacharjee made that very point in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

As $u^2=1-x^2$ where $u$ is real, $\implies1-x^2\ge0\iff x^2\le1\iff-1\le x\le1$

if $u\ge0, u=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Else $u=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$

---

Start with  $u=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to avoid sign confusion

Comment: This does not answer the question of surjectivity of the $u$-Substitution, it only sidesteps it, by providing a way in which we don't have to deal with the surjectivity of the $u$-Substitution